# how to calibrate average mean pixels to turbidity values

Tags: android, image, opencv

hi am wondering how i can convert the mean average pixel value in to turbidity values.am using the android camera to capture light coming from a clear water sample and measuring the average number of pixels from the bright region of the image ,but the reading i get is not the turbidity value so i want someone who can help me convert the mean pixel value into turbidity values. here is my code.

```
PictureCallback callback = new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Saving a bitmap to file");
        if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) { 
            Log.d("work", "work");
            Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
            Log.i("camera open", "n");
            imgToProcess=new Mat();
            Utils.bitmapToMat(picture, imgToProcess);
            Log.d("work", "work");
            Imgproc.cvtColor(imgToProcess, imgToProcess, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
            t = Core.mean(imgToProcess).toString();
```

Comment: I think that's a research question rather than programming question. You have to find it out by performing experiment and finding related literature.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a calibration curve with "solutions" (I'm pretty sure they're suspensions but whatever) at different known turbidity levels and scan them so you end up with pixel values and turbidity levels and perform a regression from that.
You can try to see if any pattern emerges by plotting the data to choose your model (at worst you can use curve fitting) and if no pattern exists use neural network regression